# Windows CE 7 connection error while develop my project in VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, embedded, compact-framework, windows-ce

I tried to create applicaton on Visual Studio 2008 (with sp1) for Windows CE7.

My earlier app is connect from VS2008 to CE5 and run on Windows CE5 devices.

But if i try to deploy project and choose "Windows CE Device",
[image: deploying screen]

Project gives this error:

> The bootstrap could not be loaded. Device Connectivity Component

But "Windows Mobile" connect from my OS (Windows 8) and i reach device directory at windows explorer..
So i dont have any connection problem this windows ce7 machine literally.

My problem in visual studio 2008.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: You may try https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2483802 and this https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/thread/2907

Comment: I can confirm for our motorola CE7 device, installing the PSDK solves this issue (see @josef's comment).

Comment: At the risk of just adding a "Me Too" comment. This is a really common question from our developers who start developing on older devices then start on a new device. The problem is certainly solved by installing the PSDK which you will need to download from the Zebra / Motorola support site (you will very likely need to supply a serial number of a device covered by warranty). http://dotfret.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/error-bootstrap-could-not-be-loaded.html

Answer (score 1):

considering that the only difference in your system stack is the device, probably it is something missing on the device itself.
My guess is you are using ActiveSync as transport when your CE5 have support for it while your CE7 doesn't.

My suggestion is to use "TCP Connect Transport" with a fixed IP as described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28VS.90%29.aspx

This is working for me.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I had same exact problem today. Had to download the platform SDK from motorola\zebra. Then an new option showed up for my exact device.

Comment: hi,
thanks for interest.
can you give this sdk link?